# PowerCLI Get-EsxCli Type Conversion Error

Tags: powershell, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, powercli

On three different servers, and one desktop, using PowerCLI 10, I am unable to call any of the EsxCli invocations, getting instead:

```
> $esxcli = Get-EsxCli -VMHost "host.f.q.d.n" -Server (Connect-VIServer "server.f.q.d.n" -User "username" -Password "*****")
> $esxcli.hardware.platform.get()
Object of type 'InternalVimApi_50.ManagedObjectReference' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.
```

Anyone else encountered this?

I have tried PowerCLI 6.5 as well, and the `-V2` option, same error.

Looking into the DLLs, it seems like it could be an overload resolution issue, but for the life of me I have not been able to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions.

If the user account permissions aren't set right, it fails with overload failure instead of anything useful.

Logged with VMware.